# Installing phpMyAdmin on Cent OS 5.5

Tags: php, linux, installation, phpmyadmin, centos5

Sorry guys,

I posted it on here by mistake... I have created it over at server fault: https://serverfault.com/questions/167302/installing-phpmyadmin-on-cent-os-5-5

Comment: You're going to have to give a bit more information. Can you access the phpMyAdmin login page at all? What error are you getting? 404?

What steps did you take with the install?

Comment: Hey Stoosh, I actually have this posted over here... Thought it was more appropriate, there are answers to some of your questions there.
http://serverfault.com/questions/167302/installing-phpmyadmin-on-cent-os-5-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the problem now... I uninstalled all instances of php / mysql / phpmyadmin, reinstalled... Set the owner of phpmyadmin to apache.apache changed the phpMyAdmin.conf to allow from all and everything seems to be working now. Thanks everyone for the help, but I have now managed to work it now.